# How can I omit a row-operation for elements in the diagonal

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I'm trying to create a program which solves linear systems using Gaussian Elimination. The program should consist of two parts. The forwards phase and a phase for Back-substitution.

Right now I am working on the forward phase. However, I can't figure out a method for treating the diagonal elements.

I've tried implementing if-statments which should do the row-operation for the element below the element on the diagonal.

```
function A = mygausselm(A) 

[m,n] = size(A); 

for k=1:n-1 %columns
    for i=1:m-1 %rows
        L = A(i+1,k)/A(k,k);
        A(i+1,:)= A(i+1,:)- L*A(k,:);

    end 
end
end
```

Take the matrix:

```
               [ 1   2  3 ]
        A=     [ 4   3  2 ]
               [ 7   5  4 ]
```

The  expected output should then be after the row-operations

```
               [ *   *  * ]
        A=     [ 0   *  * ]
               [ 0   0  * ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your i index was starting wrong. Don't start from line 1, start from the next line under the diagonal element k you work on:

```
for k=1:n-1 %columns
    for i=k+1:m %rows
        L = A(i,k)/A(k,k);
        A(i,:)= A(i,:)- L*A(k,:);
    end 
end
```

Since you know that when working on column k, all rows under row k have their first (k-1) elements zero, you can avoid operations on them:

```
for k=1:n-1 %columns
    for i=k+1:m %rows
        L = A(i,k)/A(k,k);
        A(i,k:end)= A(i,k:end)- L*A(k,k:end);
    end 
end
```

Comment: It seems that it works kinda poorly for non-square matrices. I'm not sure how familiar you're with gaussian elimination. But how could I optomize this for non-square matrices? Thank you btw!

Comment: Firstly, did this answer cover your original question? If yes, I suggest you edit your question to reflect better the actual problem - the title is kind of misleading.
Secondly, you are supposed to ask a new question for a follow up but let's consider this for a bit before you do it.

Comment: 3) Gauss elimination for non-square matrices can be tricky. If your end-goal is to solve a system, are you sure you'll get a system with a unique solution so that Gauss elimination can work?
4) Keep in mind that your provided code for getting an upper triangular matrix won't work for special cases where when working on k-column the A(k,k)=0. In those cases you will also need row-swaps.

Comment: I apologise. You did answer my question. My assignment is to write a program inorder to solve a linear system of equations using Gaussian Elimination for a 
"m x n" matrix. I have some thing to add to the existing part(above) like back-substitution and for the mentioned special cases A(k,k) =0

Comment: No need to :) In that case, you have to consider your coefficient matrix A(mxn), if it is to have a unique solution, only n out of the m rows will be linearly independent. What kind of systems are you solving and notice poor performance? For a couple hundred rows I would assume it should work reasonably fine/fast. (actually I erased the previous comment about gauss-elimination performance since in a "normal-sized" system it should be fine) Performance-wise there are not many things to do apart to vectorize & avoid unnecessary operations - and in the answer above we did.

Comment: Apart from that, just work on the right-hand-side vector simultaneously with the main matrix

Comment: It was a poor choice of words. By "optimize" I meant that i'm unsure if my method(code) is apt for solving non-square matrices. So to be clear, my current code should be able to solve non-square matrices, after I add back-substitution? The hard part is to find solutions when they are infinite, i'm mosty unsure about that. Because if the linear system have no solutions, I could just end the program and input a new matrix(A). However if the system has infinitly many solutions, how would the program recognize that and output a single solution? Your answers have been an tremendous help.

Comment: Unfortunately no. This algorithm all it does is ensure that all elements below the main diagonal are zero, whether A is square or not. It will fail to do so if you don't handle cases where A(k,k) happens to be zero (note, I'm not referring to the original matrix A(k,k), but the element in position (k,k) after you have processed the first (k-1) columns). Up to here, this is typical gaussian-elimination. (1/2)

Comment: By the end of the elimination, you may have rows that are all-zeros (if you swapped lines to handle A(k,k)=0 those will be at the bottom). The rest of non-zero rows, assume q<=m in number: If q>n the system is overconstrained, no solution. However, you can use least-squares or other methods to find an optimal solution. If q=n, the system has exactly one solution, do backwards substitution. If q<n you system is underconstrained, you have infinite solutions. (2/2). Glad the discussion helped :)

Comment: I'm supposed to use Gaussian Elimination( which im supposed to write from scratch). Which would constitute a forward-phase and back-substitution. So I think other methods apart from back-sub are excluded. No solution case should be no problem to handle. I would just then terminate the program, given that I can write code which recognizes it. If q<n (I assume q= rows & n=columns), meaning infinite solutions,  would back-substitution still be acceptble method to solve for x(for Ax=b)?

Comment: How could it? What would be the result since there are infinite solutions? Short answer, no. Long answer, you can find solution as a function of (n-q) parameters but probably outside this scope.

Comment: So I could both disregard systemts with infinte solutions and no solutions. Would that just not leave me with a unique solution which has a linear  system q=n?

Comment: What you can disregard is up to your assignment. However what you are in the process of implementing here is solving a linear system (mxn) with m>=n where only n out of those m rows are linearly independent. (Basically an (nxn) system )

Comment: Try with your code a gauss elimination in a 2x3 system, namely [1 1 1; 1 2 2]. This is small enough to do it even by hand. After elimination, you get [1 1 1; 0 1 1]. That's a set of two equations: x1+x2+x3=b1 and x2+x3=b2. How are you gonna solve the second one so that you can backward substitute to the first one? You can't without any additional constraints. Invest to the theory behind it. Your problem in this case was not how to program it, you would figure that out sooner or later :) But missing how the method works would have you stuck there forever wondering why.

Comment: Do you mean the theory for back-substitution? If so, I've read it and I feel pretty confident about it. What constraits would are you thinking of?:)

Comment: I meant linear systems, rank of a matrix and linear independency of vectors (you can see each row as a vector), solution for underdetermined or overdetermined (approximation actually) systems and generally what is behind those procedures (elimination, substitution, etc). By constraints, I meant either an extra equation (or inequalities in the general case), that would be provided by the problem you are solving, nothing extra you can add!

Comment: To sum up. For a system to have a unique solution, it has to be that the matrix coefficient A (mxn) has m>=n and is of rank n (meaning that only n rows are linearly independent). A special case is the square matrix A (nxn) of rank n, meaning all rows are linearly independent (the matrix is invertible). This does not have to do with the method you use to solve the system, this depends solely on the coefficient matrix A. Then, in case your matrix falls under the above category so that it has a unique solution, you can use gauss elimination etc to solve it. Hope it spread some clarity there. :)